# Order by Start/End Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to sort a table that has two columns, `StartStep` & `EndStep` (text columns) as so:

```
ObjectName | StepName      | StartStep     | EndStep
-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------
Obj1       | FirstStep     | NULL          | SecondStep
Obj1       | SecondStep    | FirstStep     | NextStep
Obj1       | NextStep      | SecondStep    | FourthStep
Obj1       | FourthStep    | NextStep      | NULL
Obj2       | SomethingElse | NULL          | AfterThat
```

etc...

I need to sort so that the `StartStep` with no `EndStep` for each `ObjectName` is first, and then follow the path downwards so that the next `StartStep` is the `EndStep` of the preceding record.

Using SQL Server 2014 so I'm thinking possibly some type of sort using `LAG/LEAD`...but I'm lost.

I've searched, but not found anything directly on point, so if you mark this as a duplicate please provide the link to the "duplicate" post - clearly I'm not using the correct search terms otherwise. Please help!

Comment: If you used a numeric value for Steps, maybe with a supporting lookup table to get the names you can sort by ObjectName, StepNumber.

Comment: I wish that was possible, but I don't think I can. A bit more background (not directly needed for the question) - I'm attempting to create a script that will list out the steps of SSIS Packages via the XML. The way the order is listed therein is the PrecedenceConstraint tag, which is all text. So I can't really create a sorting table as the precedences vary from package to package, and packages vary from server to server.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this, but you're saying the `EndStep` of NULL should be first but the `StartStep` of the second row should be that `EndStep` which is NULL?  Do you mean that the `StartStep` of the first row `FourthStep` should be the `EndStep` of the second?

Comment: The first row should be the `StartStep` for which it does not exist as an `EndStep` for that `ObjectName` (which indicates that nothing precedes it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something recursive:

```
CREATE TABLE d
    ([ObjectName] varchar(4), [StepName] varchar(13), [StartStep] varchar(13), [EndStep] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO d
    ([ObjectName], [StepName], [StartStep], [EndStep])
VALUES
    ('Obj1', 'FourthStep', 'FourthStep', NULL),
    ('Obj1', 'FirstStep', 'FirstStep', 'SecondStep'),
    ('Obj1', 'NextStep', 'NextStep', 'FourthStep'),
    ('Obj1', 'SecondStep', 'SecondStep', 'NextStep'),
    ('Obj2', 'SomethingElse', 'SomethingElse', 'AfterThat')
;

with cte as
(
select 0 as level, objectname, stepname, startstep, endstep from d where endstep is null
union all
select level + 1 as level, d.objectname, d.stepname, d.startstep, d.endstep from d inner join cte on cte.startstep = d.endstep
)


select * from cte order by objectname, level
```

Hopefully there aren't so many steps to the recursion that it overruns what SQLS is capable of (100 steps by default)

Here I actually build the tree in reverse, from the last step (endstep is null) back to the first, keeping a level counter as I go. I do this because outer join aren't allowed in recursive queries, and a simple way to get the null in a startstep=endstep predicate is to start with a row where endstep is null and work backwards (so the join never has to operate on a row where endstep is null). Sorting the level ascending puts the rows in the order you're asking for (any given row depends on row-below-it style). If you order by `level desc`, you'll see them in "order of operation" style

This query omits your Obj2 because it doesn't have a null endstep. I assume it's because obj2 rows are missing from your question

Comment: Recursion ftw. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have or will add a sequence, it becomes a small matter of `lead() over()`

**Example -- Please Note the Seq Column**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Seq] Int,[ObjectName] varchar(50),[StepName] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Obj1','FirstStep')
,(2,'Obj1','SecondStep')
,(3,'Obj1','NextStep')
,(4,'Obj1','FourthStep')
,(1,'Obj2','SomethingElse')

Select *  
      ,StartStep  = StepName
      ,EndStep    = lead(StepName,1) over (Partition By ObjectName Order by Seq)
 From @YourTable
 Order By ObjectName,Seq
```

**Returns**

```
Seq ObjectName  StepName        StartStep       EndStep
1   Obj1        FirstStep       FirstStep       SecondStep
2   Obj1        SecondStep      SecondStep      NextStep
3   Obj1        NextStep        NextStep        FourthStep
4   Obj1        FourthStep      FourthStep      NULL
1   Obj2        SomethingElse   SomethingElse   NULL
```

Comment: I don't think he means this. I think we see the data as he has it, and he's saying he wants to recursively start with startstep is null,, then the next row in the sequence is th row where startstep is = the null row's endstep.. If it were a recursively conencted query it would be ordered by the level

Comment: @CaiusJard You may be right.  I'll give it a second read.  Thanks

Comment: @CaiusJard Yup... deleting

Answer (score 0):

You could also  use a case

```
  select  * 
  from  my_table  

  order by  case when endstep  is null  then 0 else  1 end asc , startStep , endStep
```